# How to get single word or a range of words in a Text component react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, text, mobile, expo

Like if I have a whole sentence e.g `My name is Bilal Riaz` wrapped in a `Text` component. On tapping `Bilal`, I want to get(console) it.
Moreover, If I long press on `Bilal` and drag it to the word `Riaz`, the `Bilal Riaz` text would be there.

Answer (score 1):

First split the text
then after create one array and push every word into array as TouchableView

like `ViewsItem.push(<TouchableOpacity onPress={'run your function '}><Text> {'your name '}</Text></TouchableOpacity>)`

and then after use  text.map(item => {return item; })}   inside return

Comment: Good for a single word but not feasible with multi-words.

Comment: when you split the text that time your string convert into array after using for loop you can push every array item into Touchable view and use this array in return method e.g text.map(item => {return item; })}